# How to get distinct row by parallel running multiple script in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parallel-processing

I have large table and I need to do some one time processing on each record of table. Processing take 1 second for 1 row. Table has more than 500k record . I can't go with one query. I'm planning to  run my query parallel by 5 part. Each run on 100k records. How to read distinct 100k record by each query so that 1 row process only once.

Comment: processing as in updating? What do you mean you are going to run it in parallel? Fire off 5 update statements at once? Your question is unclear

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using ntile.  Here is an example:

```
select column1, ntile(5) over (order by Column1)
from
(
select 1 as Column1
union all select 2
union all select 3
union all select 4
union all select 5
union all select 6
union all select 7
union all select 8
union all select 9
union all select 10
) as b
```